# How can you add an email to a github commit if you already pushed it?

Tags: git, github

Lots of OSS repositories use CLA assistant bot to sign a contribution agreement. If you pushed a commit, how can you then add the email address if it wasn't initially configured in your GIT environment before?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-to-change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-gi/750182#750182

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the author and committer name and e-mail of multiple commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-to-change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-gi)